# First ever game to alternate platforming or run-and-gun stages with scrolling shoot em up stages

Tags: gaming-history

Title pretty much covers it. I think the predecessor to Cybernator is the earliest I know (1990) but I wouldn't be surprised if there are earlier examples. I suspect the inspiration may have come from Thexder, which is a similar idea but not quite the same.

Update: The original Mario Land qualifies and is actually older - 1989. From the Wikipedia page:

> Two of the game's twelve levels are "forced-scrolling" Gradius-style
> shooters where Mario helms a submarine or airplane and fires
> projectiles towards oncoming enemies, destructible blocks and bosses.

Hopefully that clarifies what I'm talking about.

Comment: Do you mean shoot em up games that involved platforms (side scrolling style etc) or games where you had differing levels that were either or

Comment: You mean like the Contra which was released on February 20, 1987?

Comment: Or the Metroid of August 6, 1986?

Comment: I'm talking about one stage is a platform stage (or platform shooter or run and gun if you prefer) and the next stage is a scrolling shoot em up stage like R-Type etc. What Rayman did and I think Earthworm Jim did it too. And Jim Power, and quite a few others.

Comment: I've edited the title to clarify (I shouldn't have used the word "combine" - I just meant combine within a single game).

Comment: I think this question would be better with screens (or links from the games to examples of what you mean) as I am not convinced a textual description will serve.  I'm sure it's clear to you, but the clarify did not help me understand anymore than originally and I'm unmotivated to look at those games to either remember or try and see what you might mean.

Comment: Agreed, though when I substitute the word "alternate" in the question for "combine", especially given the suggestions already made, it makes more sense to me. And purely going with that, as well as to throw more contenders in to the mix: Rolling Thunder (1986) developed by Namco, Gradius (1985) developed by Konami, Hover Attack (1985) by Compac, Kagirinaki Tatakai (1983) developed by Enix Corporation. I would hazard a guess the earliest predecessor to Cybernator was likely developed and published in Japan...

Comment: I've updated and clarified the question again.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, then I would say probably "Brain Breaker" by Hiroshi Ishikawa (1985). It's akin to the games you've stated "Cybernator", "Mario Land", "Thexder". More so, than some of its contemporaries like, "Baraduke" (1985) and the already commented (by MokeyZeus) "Metroid". Though finding something made earlier is not unlikely. Check out the gameplay for yourself and let me know: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dfwl8MTjY0E

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting! Referring back to my original question though you'll see I noted that Thexder is similar but not quite what I'm talking about. There's a pretty seamless transition there between running and jetpacking on the same level. I'm talking about fully distinct R-Type-type levels mixed in with either classic platformer (Mario) or shooting platformer (Contra) levels.

Comment: Okay, so after wracking my brains and doing some more digging up, at first, I thought maybe "Wonder Boy III: Monster Lair" (1988) which alternates between a regular scrolling platformer and a flying scrolling shooter. Then I thought maybe "The Guardian Legend" (also 1988), which is also a hybrid, action-adventure/shmup (shoot 'em up), which although the flying-shooter portions are R-type-esque the alternate genre is not per your spec.

Comment: Next I discovered "Mad City" (also 1988), once again although multi-genre it isn't quite (I don't think) what you are looking for. Then going back even further I found "Major Havoc" a vector-based arcade game from 1983 by Atari. This includes distinct platform shooter/run and gun stages with scrolliong shooter stages. Check it out and let me know if I'm getting closer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94j4u6ztiKc&t=748s

Comment: Sorry for seemingly spam posting, but as a relevant addendum for your consideration I would also submit "Xain'd Sleena", a 2-genre arcade platformer, side-scrolling shooter by Technos from 1986, not as early as my last suggestion but pre-dating the others I mentioned.

Comment: These both look really cool and very impressive for such early games! Definite Turrican vibes from Xain'd Sleena (maybe an inspiration) and double jump in 1986! Both of these definitely fit my criteria. If you could pop Major Havoc into an answer then I don't think anyone is going to beat 1983.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this a remarkably interesting question to research, taking me down memory lane in some instances and the idiomatic rabbit hole in others. The earliest game I could find that satisfied the criteria defined by Sam was "**Major Havoc**" (or "The Adventures of Major Havoc") a vector-based arcade action game developed and published by Atari Inc. in 1983.

It features alternating levels of spaceship (the "Catastrofighter") combat, a la "Tempest" (1981), and Major "Rex Havoc" himself running and gunning in a platform environment, a la "Berzerk" (1980)/"Spike" (1983).

Gameplay footage can be seen here:

Furthermore, I recommend the channel for fans of retro-gaming.

Comment: Many thanks for your determination and persistence :-)

Comment: You're very welcome! :)